# matplotlib imgplot: the plot does not appear

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe X_test and I want to display the 1000th element of this dataframe as an image. I use imgplot from matplotlib and the code is the following:

```
         import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
         import matplotlib.image as mpimg
         image = X_test.iloc[[999]]
         arr = np.asarray(image)
         imgplot = plt.imshow(arr)
         plt.show()
```

The commands are executed without any error message but nothing appears.

Could you help me?  Thank you.

Comment: Can't test it for you since `X_test` is not given. Where do you use `mpimg`?

Comment: can you plot anything else besides an image? If you replace `plt.imshwo()`  by `plt.plot([1,2,3])` does the plot show up?

Comment: Yes the plt.plot([1,2,3]) plot shows up.